# Rails AJAX request for partial will not load locals despite having them assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml, partials, locals

So I have been slamming my head with thing for hours not sure where to go.
I am trying to render a partial `_show.html.haml` within my `index.html.haml`. However I continue to have issues with the locals not loading despite having them declared when I render.

This is my controller.

```
def show
  @table = params["id"]
  @bank = Bank.find(params["bank_id"])
  @table_contents = @bank.table_config.as_json.first[1][@table]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :partial => 'manage/table_configs/show', locals: { table: @table, table_contents: @table_contents}}
  end
end
```

This is `Index.html.haml`

```
#all-tables
  %h1 Table Configurations
  %br/
  %table#table_configs_table.pretty
    %tr
      %th Table Name
    %tbody
      - @tables.each do |table|
        %tr
          %td= link_to table.titleize, manage_bank_table_config_path(@bank, table), remote: true

 #show-table
   %h2 Show

:javascript
  $('#show-table').html('#{escape_javascript(render(partial: "manage/table_configs/show", :locals => {:table => @table, :table_contents => @table_contents, :bank => @bank}))}');
```

This is my partial that i'm trying to render that keeps returning this error.
`undefined method 'titleize' for nil:NilClass`

`_show.html.haml`

```
%h1= table.titleize
%br/
%table.table.table-striped.table-hover.pretty
  %tr
    %th Column Name
    %th Column State
  %tbody
    - table_contents.each do |key, value|
      %tr
        %td=key.to_s.titleize
        %td=value.values.first.to_s.titleize
%br/
=link_to "Edit Table", edit_manage_bank_table_config_path(@bank, table), class: "btn btn-sm"
=link_to "All Tables", manage_bank_table_configs_path(@bank), class: "btn btn-sm"
```

Any help in figuring out why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT

I should also add that this works fine without AJAX

Comment: Are you sure you want value.values.to_s and not just value.to_s ... In the show partial?

Comment: `@tables` is not declared anywhere so it is nil by default.  I see `@table` declared but not `@tables`

Comment: `@tables` is declared in my index controller

Comment: yes `value.values.to_s` is correct It is a `value` is a hash

Answer (score 0):

you should compile the template outside js first

`<% compiled_template = escape_javascript(render(partial: "manage/table_configs/show", :locals => {:table => @table, :table_contents => @table_contents, :bank => @bank}))%>`

then add the compiled using jquery like so

`$('#show-table').html("#{compiled_template}")`